# PHP: linked list implementation issue with reference to object?

Tags: php

I am creating a linklist class and have some confusion about reference to objects.

As per my understanding by default object is copied by reference. $Obj1 = $Obj2. $Obj1 is a alias of $Obj2.

Can someone please point out which one is correct in linkedlist implementation.

```
$firstNode->next = $this->first;---> seems to be correct
             or 
$firstNode->next =& $this->first;

$this->first = $firstNode;-----> seems to be correct as $firstNode is an object
             or 
$this->first = & $firstNode;
```

code:

```
class Node {
    public $element;
    public $next;

public function __construct($element){
    $this->element = $element;
    $this->next = NULL;
  }
}

class Linklist {

    private $first;
    private $listSize;

 public function __construct(){      
    $this->first = NULL;
    $this->listSize = 0;
}

public function InsertToFirst($element){
     $firstNode = new Node($element);
     $firstNode->next = $this->first;   // or $firstNode->next =& $this->first;
     $this->first = $firstNode;  // or $this->first = & $firstNode;
 }
```

Comment: (If this is not a homework) Why would you create a linked list in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you do not need to use reference assignment (aliasing/`&`) for your linked list if each node is an object itself and `next` and `first` are objects of that node-type as well.

See [Objects and References  in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) to understand the details.

Comment: you mean $this->first = $firstNode; is correct? no need to add & in front of object?

Comment: @Praveen: Correct in the sense that it does the job. You should write getter and setter methods for these properties and ensure that always the correct type is assigned. - Added a useful link in the answer as well.

Comment: i saw a code http://www.codediesel.com/php/linked-list-in-php/ which assigns object using &, so i asked this counter question

Comment: That code is probably influenced by PHP version 4 (even it is version 5 code), in PHP 4 this was necessary, since PHP 5 not any longer. See the link I left in the answer for a better understanding.

Comment: This is not needed in PHP5 anymore. Assigning an object to a variable doesn't create a copy of the object.

Comment: Why create a linked list class when PHP already provides Doubly Linked Lists as part of the SPL library? http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php

Comment: @Mark, thanks for pointing out..  i am planning to learn all ds for fun :)